# SQL involving MAX of two colums and Group BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

So... i got a table like this:

```
id  group   number  year
1   1       1       2000
2   1       2       2000
3   1       1       2001
4   2       1       2000
5   2       2       2000
6   2       1       2001
7   2       2       2001
8   2       3       2001
```

And i need to select the bigger number of the bigger year for each group. So i expect the result of the exemple to be:

```
3   1       1       2001
8   2       3       2001
```

any ideias?
OBS: using Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    row_number() over (partition by "group" order by "year" desc, "number" desc ) x
  FROM table1
) x
WHERE x = 1;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd78e/2

Comment: It seens  that it works fine. But i'm using HQL and i can not use subqueries in "FROM ...." only on "SELECT" or " WHERE". :/

Comment: You can create a view in the database using this query, and in HQL you can use just: `select * from view_name`

Answer (score 2):

If it's just certain rows you want to get you can use `DISTINCT`. If you want different maximums on the same rows you could use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("group") * FROM tbl
  ORDER BY "group", year DESC, id DESC;
```